# Problem in hiding link through jQuery

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lnkbtnPrevious','')" class="pager-link" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkbtnPrevious">Previous</a>
<a class="pager-link" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkbtnNext">Next</a>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkbtnPrevious").attr("href") == "") {
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkbtnPrevious").css("display", "none");
            }
            if ($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkbtnNext").attr("href") == "") {
                $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkbtnNext").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I am trying to hide the link if it is not contains href. but this code not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr('attributename')` will return `undefined`, not an empty string when the attribute `attributename` is not found.

simply do

```
if (!$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkbtnNext").attr("href")) {
   //.... your code ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkbtnPrevious").hide();
```

instead of modifying the css.

And as Stefano pointed out, use `if(!$('mydiv').attr('foo'))` to check if an attribute is present, do not compare with the empty string.

Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but some browser might act funny if a link doesn't have an href, this behavior might be dependent of the doctype.